# Audio data format being rejected in Speech Studio

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I'm uploading a zip file of audio data to Custom Speech project in Speech Studio. However, the files are being rejected after upload.

I've tried sox and ffmpeg to do the file conversion. The output of sox is matching the requirements on the doc pages. I don't understand why the files are being rejected.

`sox.exe" --i audio1.wav`

```
Input File     : 'audio1.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 16000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:02.27 = 36320 samples ~ 170.25 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 72.7k
Bit Rate       : 256k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

I zip up the file and upload it. I believe this matches with the requirements below.

```
File format RIFF (WAV)
Sample rate 8,000 Hz or 16,000 Hz
Channels    1 (mono)
Maximum length per audio    2 hours
Sample format   PCM, 16-bit
Archive format  .zip
Maximum archive size    2 GB
```

The UI displays "Failed to upload data. Please check your data format and try to upload again."

I can only believe that there's an issue with the service.

Answer (score 0):

I have little experience with sox, but you use ffmpeg with:
ffmpeg.exe -i  -ac 1 -ar 16000

You can find ffmpeg here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/
It is free.

Hope this helps.